# ClassCastException with Spring and eclipselink configuration

Tags: spring, eclipselink, classcastexception

I'm getting a strange error while using Spring with eclipselink

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The class, [MigriertAttributeTransformer] cannot be used as an AttributeTransformer.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class MigriertAttributeTransformer cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.transformers.Attrib
uteTransformer (MigriertAttributeTransformer is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleThrowawayClassLoader @6cc86152; org .eclipse.persistence.mappings.transformers.AttributeTransformer is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I got answers saying it's something to do with Spring classloader but did not find anything useful.

I tried changing versions of Spring and eclipselink, changing properties in persistence.xml but still problem persists

Edit
---
I am using Spring 5.2.7 version with eclipselink 2.7.6

These are my properties in persistence.xml

```
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
                    
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
  <!-- from iau-maris-opa -->
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.bind-paramaters" value="true" />
  <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle" />
  <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="None"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="commit" />
  <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.reference-mode" value="WEAK" />
  <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
  <property name="eclipselink.weaving.eager" value="true" />
  <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.mode" value="Always"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.sessions-xml" value="Testsessions.xml"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.session-name" value="default_test"/>
                  <property name="eclipselink.orm.validate.schema" value="boTLDescriptor.xml"/>
   <!--  <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value=""/>-->

</properties>
```

And spring-context.xml looks like this

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml" />
  <!-- <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />-->
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit_test" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
      <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
      <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
      <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.Oracle12Platform"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="jpaDialect">
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />
  </property>
  <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
    <props>
      <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">false</prop>
      <!--  <prop key="eclipselink.weaving.lazy">true</prop>-->
      <!--  <prop key="eclipselink.weaving.internal">true</prop>-->
    </props>
  </property>

  <!-- <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
    <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver" />
      </property>-->
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
          <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
       </property>
</bean>
```

StackTrace:

```
Target Invocation Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-183] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The class, [MigriertAttributeTransformer] cannot be used as an AttributeTransformer.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class MigriertAttributeTransformer cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.transformers.Attrib
uteTransformer (de.bund.bamf.InGe.bo.MigriertAttributeTransformer is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleThrowawayClassLoader @6cc86152; org .eclipse.persistence.mappings.transformers.AttributeTransformer is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[attributeTransformerClass-->attribute-transformer/text()]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractTransformationMapping --> [DatabaseTable(attribute-mapping)])
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
        at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.createApplicationContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:213)
        at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContextLocations(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:189)
        at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:169)
        at org.springframework.test.AbstractSpringContextTests.getContext(AbstractSpringContextTests.java:140) 
        at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.setUp(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:98)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:140)
        at org.springframework.test.ConditionalTestCase.runBare(ConditionalTestCase.java:76)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:130)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:241)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:236)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.Entit
yManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [persistenceUnit_test] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-9005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.SessionLoaderException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while loading the project-xml file [META-INF/de.bund.bamf.InGe.boTLDescriptor.xml].
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-106] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [setAttributeTransformerClass] on the object is throwing an exception.
Argument: [class MigriertAttributeTransformer]
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Target Invocation Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-183] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The class, [MigriertAttributeTransformer] cannot be used as an AttributeTransformer.
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class MigriertAttributeTransformer cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.transformers.Attrib
uteTransformer (MigriertAttributeTransformer is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleThrowawayClassLoader @6cc86152; org .eclipse.persistence.mappings.transformers.AttributeTransformer is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[attributeTransformerClass-->attribute-transformer/text()]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractTransformationMapping --> [DatabaseTable(attribute-mapping)])
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2109)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2085)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:350)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:316)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [persistenceUnit_test] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-9005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.SessionLoaderException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while loading the project-xml file [META-INF/boTLDescriptor.xml].
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-106] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [setAttributeTransformerClass] on the object is throwing an exception.
Argument: [class MigriertAttributeTransformer]
Internal Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

dependencies in pom

````
<eclipselink.version>2.7.6</eclipselink.version>
<spring.version>5.2.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
   
<dependencies>  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>${ojdbc.version}</version>
    <!--scope>runtime</scope-->
  </dependency>
   
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version><!--5.2.7.RELEASE-->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version><!--2.5.6-->
  </dependency>
   
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
    <exclusions>

      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <!-- <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>jakarta.persistence</artifactId>
       </exclusion>-->
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```
````

session.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sessions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4.2">
    <session xsi:type="server-session">
        <name>default_test</name>
        <!-- see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/web.1111/b32441/sescfg.htm#JITDG93429 -->
        <!-- see for eclipselink: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e25034/tlandwls.htm#TLADG131 -->

        <primary-project xsi:type="xml">META-INF/boTLDescriptor.xml</primary-project>

        </session>
</sessions>
```

boTLDescriptor.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<object-persistence version="Eclipselink Persistence Services - 0.1-incubation"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <name>bo</name>
    <class-mapping-descriptors>

        <class-mapping-descriptor xsi:type="relational-class-mapping-descriptor">
            <class>EmployeeImpl</class>
            <alias>Employee</alias>
            <primary-key>
                <field table="Employee" name="ID" xsi:type="column"/>
            </primary-key>

        <attribute-mappings>
                <attribute-mapping xsi:type="direct-mapping">
                    <attribute-name>id</attribute-name>
                    <field table="Employee" name="ID" xsi:type="column"/>
                </attribute-mapping>
               <attribute-mapping xsi:type="transformation-mapping">
                    <attribute-name>migriert</attribute-name>
                    <read-only>true</read-only>
                    <attribute-transformer>MigriertAttributeTransformer</attribute-transformer>
                </attribute-mapping>
</attribute-mappings>

</class-mapping-descriptor>
    </class-mapping-descriptors>
</object-persistence>
```

Comment: Far toot little information to even begin answering this. What is your configuration, what are the versions you are using, what is the **full stacktrace**...

Comment: Hi Deinum, edited the text with version and configurations.Here is the stack trace

Comment: It almost looks like you have a wrong mix of EclipseLink jars in your classpath or incompatible JPA version. Please include your dependencies (I assume you are using something like Maven or Gradle to manage the dependencies). Also does your own custom converter actually implement said interface?

Comment: yes ,the class implements the interface and added dependency

Comment: Well you are already mixing Spring 2.5.6 jars (`spring-test`) with Spring 5.2.x jars. Never mix jars from different versions of a framework.

Comment: i have tried replacing spring test with 5.2 but still i get same error

Comment: The versions should at least match. Which java version are you using, the EclipseLink version you are using is pretty old, so might not even be compatible with the java version in use.

Comment: i use java 8 .I have tried using java 17 with spring 5.2 version but still the error persists.

Comment: Looking at your config I suspect it has to do with your instrumentation setup which introduces another classloader. What if you remove the instrumentation setup? Your `persistence.xml` is also being partially overridden by your config in xml. Why not put all that in XML to begin with?

Comment: Hi Deinum, i just removed instrumentation loader and other properties from the bean ,but no luck .somehow it uses two classloaders  but iam not using any duplicate jars or mismatch jars

Comment: There is the `SimpleThrowawayClassLoader` are you running with a javaagent? Or have other loadtime weaving things in place?

Comment: nothing i do .In persistence xml , i do have loadtime weaving configurations  set to static. Anyhow in spring emf ,i set it to false

Comment: Not directly related to your issue, but what is the "eclipselink.orm.validate.schema" property in there for? I don't think it takes a file name as a value (I would have thought it should be true or false). You have loadTimeWeaver set, try removing it as it could be why the class loaders to load your transformer impl cannot be used against classes loaded with the application class loader. Otherwise, show a bit more in the config and strip out what isn't absolutely needed - you may want to debug with your own EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter implementation class.

Comment: Hi Chris,the property eclipselink.orm.validate.schema is used if we have external mapping xml but i removed it and commented the loadTimeweaver from spring emf bean. Still error is there .I have attached session.xml and descriptor.xml where attribute transformer tag is used

Comment: Issue is not in the config files within EclipseLink; while this might affect if EclipseLink uses the getClassLoader() or getNewTempClassLoader() on the PersistenceUnitInfo Spring builds, the root cause is that classes loaded from them MUST still match up with the application class loader used to load EclipseLink, and they are not. Only things I can think of is if your test or other Spring bean classes are building their own class loader with EclipseLink classes on it and using that for the persistence unit.